# Resizing stand alone images

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio, standalone

I'm trying to use the standalone package to produce .jpeg files from my TiKz code. I use TexStudio and Windows 8.1. I have both pdf2svg and ImageMagik installed.

If I use the following code, TeXstudio hangs on me.

```
\documentclass[convert={density=800x300,outext=.jpg}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1) node [midway] {Example};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I change the code to:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1) node [midway] {Example};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then use a terminal to convert the file the command

```
convert standalone_test.pdf standalone.jpeg
```

Produces a horribly small image [image: horribly small image]

Using the terminal command

```
convert standalone_test.pdf -resize 800x300 standalone_test.jpeg
```

Simply gives me a black rectangle [image: a black rectangle]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the convert command, use the "density" option as in "convert -density 300x300 file.pdf file.png"

Comment: Hi James, although this helps with the size, now the text in the resultant file (axis labels for example) looks a bit shoddy. ![Image](http://i.imgur.com/nE9NpM9.jpg) Any idea how to rectify this?

Comment: Increase the "300x300" to "600x600" or higher as necessary.  The density numbers relate the PDF size to the number of pixels.  For example, a 1 inch square in PDF will result in a 300x300 pixel PNG file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`standalone` can do automatic conversions with `convert` options. It assumes that Imagemagick `convert` is installed but for windows systems it uses `imgconvert` instead of `convert` to avoid name confusion with another program.

The problem is that ImageMagick's converter is also named `convert` in windows systems and automatic conversions fail because `imgconvert` is not found.

A possible solution could be to specify `convertexe=convert` suboption in `standalone` `convert` option. This way, the correct executable is called even in windows systems.

As a simple example something like

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert={convertexe=convert,density=800x300,outext=.jpg}]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1) node [midway] {Example};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

should not hang in TeXstudio.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. This code indeed doesn't hang TeXstudio and does exactly as I want.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have created your PDF image, you can convert it at difference resolutions using varying `density` values in the `convert` command.

```
convert -density 150x150 sample.pdf sample_150.png
convert -density 300x300 sample.pdf sample_300.png
convert -density 600x600 sample.pdf sample_600.png
```

[image]

[image]

[image]