# Tikzipicture to png

Tags: tikz-pgf

I get the following error message when trying to get a png from a tikzipicture.

[image: Error message]

This is my code simplifyed code (without the actual data)

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Number of doctors, % label x axis
    ylabel=Number of MPA, % label y axis
    axis lines=left, %set the position of the axes
legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north east},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!!

[image: my setting to include shell escapes]

Comment: Perhaps this should be tagged [tag:miktex]? At any rate, the MWE compiles without trouble for me, but then there is no conversion to PNG involved. (And as a Mac user, I am unlikely to be able to help anyhow.)

Comment: You need to check which external convert application you have. Is imagemagick installed? And if yes how can you call convert? With the old `convert` or with the new `magick convert`? Try out `convert --help` on a command line to find out. In my case I have the old `convert` and then so I had to use `\documentclass[convert={convertexe=convert}]{standalone}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try out if it works.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299561/1952

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Shell escape works now. But I get the following error message: standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful! (standalone) There might be something wrong with your (standalone) conversation software or the file permissions!] the following solution did not help: (tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205490/…) Any ideas? Add:this was my mwe: [\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1) node [midway] {Example}; \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}]

Comment: Did you check which external convert application you have? Did you try the key `convert={convertexe=convert}` ?

Comment: SOLVED: \documentclass[tikz,convert={density=300,outext=.png}]{standalone} used this and installed Ghostscript. Thanks a lot!