# Rounded corners for a background image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, backgrounds, rounded-corners

Here is my MWE taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463075/crop-not-scale-the-background-image-and-produce-an-image-instead-of-a-pdf/463077?noredirect=1#comment1165273_463077):

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{ eso-pic,tikz, lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\linespread{2}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt, rounded corners=10pt] at ([yshift=8pt]pic cs:start) {%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}

\tikzmark{start}\lipsum[1-1]\tikzmark{end}

\end{document}
```

I would like the background image to be with rounded corners. But it does not work.

How do I get the background image with rounded corners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution with `tcolorbox`. As `blankest` option suppresses rounded corners, its effects have been simulated with `boxsep=0t` and other geometry parameters.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx, lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myminipage}[3][]{
     enhanced,
%    blankest, 
%    rounded corners,
     boxsep=0pt,
     left=0pt,
     right=0pt,
     top=0pt,
     bottom=0pt,
    width=#2,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipframe}
    \node at (frame) {\includegraphics{#3}};
    \end{tcbclipframe}},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myminipage}{3cm}{example-image}
This is some text not so long like \texttt{\textbackslash{}lipsum[2]}
\end{myminipage}

\begin{myminipage}{10cm}{example-image}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myminipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use `clip` along with `rounded corners` while including image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ eso-pic,tikz, lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\linespread{2}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt, clip, rounded corners=20pt] at ([yshift=15pt,xshift=-5pt]pic cs:start) {%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth+10pt]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}   
\tikzmark{start}\lipsum[1-1]\tikzmark{end}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost there. But part of the text goes outside. Is there a way to ensure that the text remains strictly inside the image?

Comment: @deshmukh It is because the image height is less than that of the text. Either an image with height matching with text has to be used or the current image has to be stretched/zoomed.

Comment: @deshmukh you can mention `height=` along with `width=` in `includegraphics`. But this can alter the aspect ratio.

Comment: No, I tried with a very large image 744*1052 and text does go outside the rounded corners

Comment: @deshmukh  We are scaling the image such that the with is equal to `textwidth`. So the image height with respect to its width matters not the absolute height. Try with another image having a height more than its width. Say 1052 *744 :)

Comment: Thanks. I did. Still the same problem. The text spills beyond the rounding of corners.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86830/discussion-between-deshmukh-and-nidhin).

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. I accepted the other answer, however, as it was more succinct.